# pagination issue: I am not seeing the list get broken into sections, it show all on each page

Tags: grails, pagination

Here is the page where I want to see 5 items per page... currently it shows 10 per page and it repeats the same 10 each page not the next group of data.

I am trying to get the paginate to work right... first to simply navigate to the next group of data would be great, second the make the number per page smaller and three how to make the whole row of data clickable so I can look at a particular item in the list? All these seems confusing.

```
    <%@ page import="tictoc.Store" %>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="layout" content="main">
            <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'store.label', default: 'Store')}" />
            <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <h1> Ticket Store </h1>
            <div>
                <table border=0 class="eventsTable">
                    <tr>

                        <th>Event</th>
                        <th>Start </th>
                        <th>End </th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    <g:each var="event" in="${events}">

                    <tr>

                        <td>${event.name}</td>
                        <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.startDate}"/></td>
                        <td><g:formatDate format="MM/dd/yyyy" date="${event.endDate}"/></td>
                        <td>${event.desc}</td>
                    </tr>

                    </g:each>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="paginateButtons">
                <g:paginate controller="store"
                    action="show"
                    params="[name:active]"
                    total="${totalEvents}" />
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the controller... I try to control the max per page to 5 and I assumed it would handle putting the right set of data as it paginates.

```
    package tictoc

    import tictoc.Event 

    class StoreController {

        Event event
        static defaultAction = "activeEvents"

        def show = {
            log.error 'exec activeEvents'
            activeEvents()
        }

        def activeEvents = {
            log.error 'exec activeEvents'

            def max    = Math.min(params.max?.toInteger() ?:5, 5)
            def offset = params.offset?.toInteger() ?: 0
            def total =  Event.count()
            def eventList = Event.getAll()

            return [events:eventList, 
                           totalEvents:total,
                           active:params.active]                  
        }
    }
```

Thirdly how can I make the paginate buttons a bit larger they are quite small: I tried adjusting the paginate tags but nothing seems to make them appear larger.

```
/
.paginateButtons {
    background: #fff url(../images/skin/shadow.jpg) bottom repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 0;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;    <--------Went from 10 to 12 still same size button
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 3px;
}
.paginateButtons a {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #ccc #aaa #aaa #ccc;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0 3px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
}
.paginateButtons span {
    padding: 4px 5px;    <------Tried this too but going from 2, 3 to 4, 5 made no impact.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is returning the same 10 every time because you are calling `getAll()` instead of `list()`. `getAll()` does exactly what it says it does, it gets all of them, unless you pass a list of IDs to get. What you want to do is list the Events, which allows you to pass `params` to your GORM call.

```
def eventList = Event.list(params)
```

Once you pass in `params` the results will reflect the pagination and smaller max per page.

As @cdeszaq mentioned, passing `params` is a good way to get off the ground, but ideally you would only pass the exact params you want. You could accomplish this by doing `Event.list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset)`.

If you view the source of the page you'll find that `<g:paginate>` uses `input` tags, so try styling that instead of `span` or `a`.

Comment: For what it's worth, passing in raw `params` to a method call can be a _very_ dangerous thing, especially as the number of Events grows.